# How to access docker container by name within a bridge network?

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I created a bridge network, so that all my containers are inside of it.

This is info about my docker network (output is truncated for readability):

```
docker network inspect bridge

"Name": "bridge",
"Containers": {
  "4ae08..d80d": {
    "Name": "zimidy.chat-server.staging",
  },
  "61cdb..1c4b": {
    "Name": "zimidy.web-server.staging",
  },
  "8c45..d391": {
    "Name": "zimidy.neo4j.staging",
  },
  "bcf..093": {
    "Name": "zimidy.api.staging",
  },
  "ca1f..c5aa": {
    "Name": "zimidy.web.staging",
  }
}, 
"Options": {
  "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
  "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
  "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
  "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
  "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
  "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
}
```

But I can't access "zimidy.web.staging" from "zimidy.web-server.staging".

I try to access it using the following code:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet requestToWebModule = new HttpGet("http://zimidy.web.staging:88/app");
HttpResponse responseFromWebModule = client.execute(requestToWebModule);
```

Which throws the following error:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: zimidy.web.staging: Name or service not known
```

How to fix such a problem?

Comment: how are you creating the network, and how are you running your containers? exact commands will be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true"

(note: you actually edited your question and removed this piece while I was writing my answer)

From the [docker networking documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network)

> Containers connected to the default `bridge` network can communicate with each other by IP address. Docker does not support automatic service discovery on the default `bridge` network. If you want containers to be able to resolve IP addresses by container name, you should use user-defined networks instead.

I understand you said you created a new network, but for whatever reason that network is behaving like the default network, which means you cannot resolve by host name.

Answer (score 2):

The containers on the default bridge network **can only access each other by IP addresses**, unless you use the `--link` [option](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/), which is considered legacy.

The better idea is to use [user-defined bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks) in which from within a container you can ping other containers by their name (this capability is called automatic service discovery.).

---

[**NOTE**]:

- Remember, the default bridge network is not recommended for production.
- [Differences between user-defined bridges and the default bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge)